# Issues with running WCF services on Debian using MONO

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, mono

I am porting a WCF service onto Debian using Mono. My mono version is 3.2.7 and XSP4 version is (Mono.WebServer2.dll) 0.4.0.0

When I added the following lines to Web.Config, I get a 
*System.ArgumentException
An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary*

```
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://127.0.0.1" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

If I remove these lines, it works alright. But I cannot access them from another machine.

These are the lines in Web.config

```
   <system.serviceModel>
   <services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="genericBehavior" name="xyz.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="soap" contract="xyz.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="rest" contract="xyz.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://127.0.0.1" />
      </baseAddresses>
```

.......
 .......

Since the issue is tied with WCF and binding I am putting one more question here. WebHttpBinding is throwing an exception

```
<endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="rest" contract="xyz.IService1" />
```

When I try to access the service I following error

```
Failed to export endpoint 'WebHttpBinding_IService1': wsdl exporter 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncodingBindingElement' threw an exception: System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncodingBindingElement.System.ServiceModel.Description.IWsdlExportExtension.ExportEndpoint (System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter exporter, System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlEndpointConversionContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoint_Internal (System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint endpoint) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

    Following the stack trace
    at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoint_Internal (System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint endpoint) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoint (System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint endpoint) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoints (IEnumerable`1 endpoints, System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.get_Metadata () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at System.ServiceModel.Description.HttpGetWsdl.GetMetadata () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at System.ServiceModel.Description.HttpGetWsdl.EnsureMetadata () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at System.ServiceModel.Description.HttpGetWsdl.Get (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message req) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
    at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Any help is appreciated. Sorry My hold on WCF itself is not so strong, please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: the version of XSP4 is wrong (it has to map to one of the git tags in this repo: https://github.com/mono/xsp), please explain how you installed mono and xsp

Comment: by "wrong" I meant: it doesn't tell enough information

Comment: Hi knocte, I got the sources from here                            
git://github.com/mono/xsp.git.  I'll post the exact version in a while. Thank you for your reply

Comment: You may want to first create this WCF service in *Windows* to verify the WCF configuration XML is valid (assuming this an option for you). From what I can see, it seems [valid.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731303(v=vs.110).aspx) You don't need to have a complete implementation of the service since this would be to just validate the WCF configuration XML.

Comment: Hi @sixto-saez, I have created a sample WCF service on Windows and tested it on both Windows and Linux. Also, I have deployed the code using MonoDevelop-opt and the sample works alright.    The service I am porting works alright on IIS, and also using Xamarian+ xsp on windows.  Only when I host it using Mono, I get the exception I posted. When I remove this from config        <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="rest" contract="xyz.IService1" />   the exception disappears

Comment: That seems like a Mono/Debian issue then. The only other thing I would try is to put a full URL (http://127.0.0.1/rest) as the address of the WebHttpBinding endpoint to see if it would make a difference (or different exception). The exception you're seeing now is actually due to a failure to generate a WSDL description of the service because the Mono WSDL exporter code is missing some feature implementation.

Comment: Hi @sixto-saez, thank you for your reply. I still get the same error. And because I have commented webHttpBinding I am unable to add the service as WCF service